# Can I ALTER an existing table schema using a post-deployment script?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

Using

- SQL Server 2008 (not R2)
- Visual Studio 2012 Premium
- SQL Server Database Project/SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)

Are there any problems\potential issues with altering a table schema using a post-deployment script?

My company has a web application (App A) whose backend database has tables that are replicated to another company application's database (App B) using CDC Replication. Making schema changes to these tables causes SSDT to use DROP/CREATE when generating the deployment script. This is a problem for App B's database that uses CDC Replication on these tables, because when the table is dropped and recreated, App B's database's CT_[table_name] tables are dropped, bringing App B down. My solution is to use a post-deployment script to make ALTERations to these tables, instead of allowing SSDT to generate DROP/CREATE. Are there any potential problems or issues with this approach?

I could really use some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could conceivably handle such table changes using a *Post-Deployment* script if you were to exclude those tables from the SSDT project model. This can be achieved in either of the following ways:

- For each of the table files involved in CDC replication, set the `Build Action` property to *None*
- Or simply remove the affected table files from the project altogether

This would prevent SSDT from attempting to perform any actions on that table at all, so you wouldn't have to worry about the comparison engine producing scripts that break your CDC instances.

Naturally, this would mean that any objects that depend on the excluded table objects (such as procs or views) would also need to be moved to Post-Deployment scripts. This would result in the **traceability of the database** being reduced, as all excluded those tables would no longer have per-file history stored in source control.

Even if a solution can be found that doesn't result in these drawbacks, for example using a pre-compare script per Ed's excellent blog post, there is the issue of **deployment atomicity** to consider. If part of the deployment occurs in the script that SSDT generates, and another part occurs in a Post-Deployment script, then it's possible for an error to occur that leaves the database in a half-deployed state. This is because SSDT only uses a transaction for the parts of the deployment that it is responsible for; anything included in a Post-Deployment script will be executed after the initial transaction is committed.

This means your Post-Deployment script needs to be written in an *idempotent* way, so that it can be re-executed if something goes wrong (sorry if that is a bit of an obvious statement... it just seems always like a good point to make whenever post-deploy scripts are mentioned!).

If a higher degree control over the way that your table changes are deployed is desired, without the potential loss of traceability or deployment atomicity, then may I suggest **considering a migrations-driven deployment tool** like ReadyRoll (disclaimer: I work for Redgate Software). ReadyRoll is a project sub-type of SSDT but uses quite a different deployment style to SSDT: instead of waiting until deployment to find out that the table will be dropped/recreated, the migration script is produced at development time, allowing changes to the sync operations to be made before committing it to source control.

For more information about how SSDT and ReadyRoll compare, have a look at the ReadyRoll FAQ:
http://www.red-gate.com/library/readyroll-frequently-asked-questions-faq

Comment: Thanks Dan(iel?), are you saying that if I DO NOT exclude the tables in question from the SSDT project model, and going forward use post-deployment scripts the SSDT comparison engine will still generate scripts to alter the schema to conform to the table definition? IOW, if I have a table definition that's known to the SSDT project, then later ALTER the table schema using post-deployment scripts (ALTER add a column); subsequent deployments SSDT will generate a script to remove the column I previously added via the post-deployment script?

Comment: BTW, the post-deploy scripts would only be run once, not every deployment.

Comment: That's correct, the SSDT comparison engine will always want to 'correct' the target database so that it squares with its model of the world. This means that, if you decided to keep the table definitions in the project, and you plan to affect those objects in Post-Deploy (e.g. adding a column, as in your example) then discipline is needed: after each deployment to your Production database, you would need to go back and update the table definitions to include the new column and merge that back to your master branch. Otherwise, as you say, the column will be dropped in the next release.

Comment: Good grief. Is there anything one can do on the CDC Replication-side that would prevent dropping of the [table]_CT tables if the source tables are DROPped and reCREATEd?

Comment: I'd love to give you some good news, but unfortunately this may be beyond my understanding of CDC (either that, or it just simply isn't possible). Apologies!

Comment: Going to have to go with the pre-compare script, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the in-built refactoring support to rename columns/tables? If you do then the deployment should generate a sp_rename.

If you are and it is a bug because of cdc:

- raise a connect item
- do your own alter but you will need to run a script before the deployment otherwise it will make the changes it want for you (I call it a pre-compare script)

See https://the.agilesql.club/Blog/Ed-Elliott/Pre-Compare-and-Pre-Deploy-Scripts-In-SSDT for more details.

Ed

Comment: Thanks Ed. There seems to be a lot of schema changes that would cause SSDT to generate DROP/CREATE, not just renames (e.g. column reorder, adding constraints/columns, column data-type change, among other things). Refactor won't work in these cases.

Comment: Ok if there is things you want to do manually you will need to use a script you run before you deploy - I normally build one into my cd pipelines I can use but don't find I have to use them too often - things like constantly re-ordering columns normally points to other issues like devs sharing dev databases or long running feature branches etc

Comment: Ed Elliott, your answer didn't seem to directly address my more generic issue, but your blog post was exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Great glad it has helped!